# Make div stretch past parent's padding?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu with links that have lines to the left of each, where upon hovering on the link, the line stretches to the left the past the width of the parent container and to the edge of the viewport, rather than forcing the text for the link to the right as it currently does.

How can I do this?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZdwLb.

HTML:

```
<nav>

    <ul id="menu">

        <li>

            <a>Menu</a>

             <div id="dropdown">

            <ul>

                <li class="navLink active"><a><div class="navLine"></div>Home</a></li>

                <li class="navLink"><a><div class="navLine"></div>About</a></li>

                <li class="navLink"><a><div class="navLine"></div>Skills</a></li>

                <li class="navLink"><a><div class="navLine"></div>Work</a></li>

                <li class="navLink"><a><div class="navLine"></div>Contact</a></li>

            </ul>

            </div>

        </li>

    </ul>

    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav
{
position: fixed;
top: 30px;
left: 30px;
z-index: 99;
}

nav ul
{
display: table;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
}

nav ul > li > a
{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
color: #fff;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 14px;
cursor: pointer;
}

nav > ul > li > a:first-of-type
{
cursor: default;
text-decoration: none;
}

.navLink > a:hover,
.navLink.active > a
{
color: #1957ef;
text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul > li:first-of-type:hover #dropdown
{
height: auto;
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
}

nav > ul > li:first-of-type:hover > a
{
opacity: 0;
transition: all linear 0.1s;
-webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
-moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
}

#dropdown
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
visibility: hidden;
height: 1px;
opacity: 0;
transition: all linear 0.1s;
-webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
-moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
}

.navLink > a
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.navLink .navLine
{
height: 2px;
width: 30px;
background: #fff;
margin-right: 10px;
transition: all linear 0.1s;
-webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
-moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
}

.navLink.active > a > .navLine,
.navLink:hover > a > .navLine
{
width: 50px;
background: #1957ef;
}

.sectionContent
{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding: 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWjyop)

I simply added this to the hover

```
.navLink.active > a > .navLine,
.navLink:hover > a > .navLine
{
  width: 57px;
  background: #1957ef;
  margin-left: -28px;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks